# Complex $sum query

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I'm working with Kettle and need to calculate how many entries have some expected values (at least two fields in an inner array).

**For example:**

```
{
    "_id":"HY1406",
    "accounts": [ 
        {
            "should_exist" : 1,
            "endpoint" : "0_AD",
            "exists" : 0,
            "short_login" : "TB6"
        },
        {
            "should_exist" : 1,
            "endpoint" : "0_AD",
            "exists" : 0,
            "short_login" : "TB7"
        },
        {
            "should_exist" : 1,
            "endpoint" : "0_AD",
            "exists" : 0,
            "short_login" : "TB8"
        }
    ]
}
```

I have to calculate how many documents have **AT LEAST** an account having `"sould_exist" = 1 AND "exists" = 0`.

How can I perform this with a MongoDB query?

Comment: what is the expected result?

Comment: Show us codes, what  you have already try.

Comment: db.collection.find({"accounts.should_exist": 1, "accounts.exists": 0}).count()

Comment: @mmu36478 , can we do it with aggregation please ?

Comment: @Styvane : I'm looking for the number of all documents which accounts field has at least one entry having "sould_exist" = 1 AND "exists" = 0

Comment: I 'm thinking about $elemMatch operator in an aggregation

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `$elemMatch` to match both the criteria of an embedded document in an array. Get a cursor with `find()` and invoke `count()`.

```
db.collection.find({
    accounts : {
        $elemMatch : {should_exist : 1, exists : 0}
    }
}).count()
```

or write your filter inside `count()`

```
db.collection.count({
    accounts : {
        $elemMatch : {should_exist : 1, exists : 0}
    }
})
```

or with aggregation

```
db.collection.aggregate([
{
    $match : {
        accounts : {
            $elemMatch : {should_exist : 1, exists : 0}
        }
    }
},
{
    $group : {
        _id : "foo",
        count : {$sum : 1}
    }
}
])
```

Comment: that seems interesting , actually , I want to calculate sums of two categories : category 1 : "sould_exist" = 1 AND "exists" = 0 and category 2 : "sould_exist" = 1 AND "exists" = 1. the result is like : { "_id" : 1.0, "numCat1" : 2, "numCat2" : 7 } how can i do such query ?

Comment: That's completely different from what you've posted in the question. *I have to calculate how many documents have AT LEAST an account having "sould_exist" = 1 AND "exists" = 0.*